# Distributed versioning of geospatial data?

Tags: spatial-database, versioning, version-control

I'm getting started on the design of a new system that would reconcile, merge, and synchronize changes made across numerous geospatial databases of common ancestry, on an ongoing basis. These databases are distributed across numerous different organizations that have an interest in eliminating duplication of effort.

I read that OpenGeo is working on a project called [GeoGit](http://opengeo.org/publications/distributedversioning/), which is interesting but seems very much a work in progress.

Are there any other tools, projects, or research that would be worth looking into?

I do not want to reinvent the wheel, but cannot seem to find much out there on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coordinating data from several sources is complicated. Your ability to "coach" the organizations you are referring to will be put to a test. How do you plan on resolving data conflicts? Are you in a position to put forward clear mandates to the participating organizations? What is your mandate in all this? What are your resourceS? Etc...

I have looked around and not found anything quite like what [Chris Holmes writes in his papers](http://blog.opengeo.org/2012/09/20/distributed-versioning-for-geospatial-data/). The paper blew me away when I read it earlier this year. I am sure that [OpenGeo](http://www.opengeo.org) would accept funding to move forward with the plans. I am also sure that your input on challenges and possible solutions working towards open standards will be equally welcome.

You could of course take a look at what ESRI is doing with regards to [ESRI versioning](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0110/versioning101.html) in ArcSDE. From what little I have seen it does not look like the works of OpenGEO.