# File GDB Feature Classes Converting Themselves to File GDB Tables

Tags: arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase, feature-class

I have GDBs in folders in a certain location in a shared dropbox. When I move the folders to another location, some of the feature classes have been converted to GDB tables.

I have never seen this before, and now all of a sudden it is happening to me all the time.

Has anyone else seen this and know what is causing it?

[image: MyGDB]

Comment: .zip the folder up before moving

Comment: fyi > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69307/issues-using-dropbox-to-sync-file-geodatabases