# What is the recommended way for team coordination in GIS (ArcGIS, QGIS, etc.)

Tags: qgis, postgis, arcgis-server, versioning, data-management

I am preparing a team of around 18 GIS analysts to work on 12h/12h work cycle to attain 24h/day work rate. This means two 9-person teams, one for each period.

All analysts will have access to various types of raster data, where they will use them to essentially register line, point and polygon features. Some of these line, point and polygon vector layers have topological rules with themselves and each other.

I would like to have access to the work progress and efficiency of each analyst. A summarized report (visual and textual) should also be automatically generated as a handover report for the next time period's analyst. Furthermore, I would love to have the power to roll back certain analysts changes to the GIS map shared by all members. All this information should be enough for the manager to make the correct decision.

I know there are database solutions such as ArcGIS server and POSTGIS, but I am not sure how I can apply them to this problem.

I would love to read what you guys have used or thought of using in the past.

Comment: Is this helpful: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/61978/8104?

Comment: Thanks. Giving it a read. Versioning will give me some of these answers.

Comment: As it stands I think your question is far too broad for our focused Q&A format because it lists a number of requirements but does not ask a question beyond seeking opinions from others with similar requirements.