# Versioning in PostGIS on PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgis, postgresql, versioning

I have a cadastral database which requires multi-user editing/updating on daily basis.

I am trying to migrate from Esri enterprise geodatabase to PostGIS/PostgreSQL. I am not sure PostGIS offers versioning option similar to the Esri versioning.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the following answer.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61978/implementing-version-control-system-for-geospatial-data

Comment: thanks @user4906240. will take a look at the link you provided.

Comment: Esri supports Enterprise geodatabase versioning in PostgreSQL databases with PostGIS, though you really ought to be at 10.4.1 or higher for an enterprise-ready solution.